# Probability, something easy!

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

Good afternoon people

suppose the function $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{sx^{2}}{zx^{2}+1}$$

How many different functions can there be, if numbers s and z are taken randomly from the set $\left\{ 0,1,0.5,2.64,-6\right\} $

I think the answer would $5\times 5= 25 -5 = 20$ . I subtract $5$ for the case where the $s=0$, because the result will always be the same: $= 0$.

I miss something perhaps ?

Cheerios.

Comment: Yes, you missed something! You subtracted too much for the case $s=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that that all $5$ values of $z$ give the same function when $s=0$. But this means you must subtract $4$, not $5$. You have $4$ too many.